# Can I clone the bytes of a C++ object, overwrite the original bytes, then copy those bytes back?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

This is purely hypothetical, but I'm not sure whether the following code will result in undefined behavior according to the C++ spec.  I'd like to make a copy of the bytes in an object, blast the object by overwriting it with zeros, then copy the old bytes back.  Can I do so without causing undefined behavior?

Sample code:

```
NonPODType o;
char bytes[sizeof(o)];

memcpy(bytes, &o, sizeof(o));
memset(&o, 0, sizeof(o));
memcpy(&o, bytes, sizeof(o));
```

Comment: I wouldn't think it would cause any weird issues, but why would you do that?  From my understanding, the net result is zero change

Comment: Interesting question.  If the answer is indeed "No", it would be interesting to see a specific example that doesn't work.  Of course, such an example might not exist in current implementations.

Comment: Definitely breaks for a class with volatile members (as the state may change between copy and set).

Comment: @MarkWilkins: It doesn't matter if there exists an example that doesn't work. The *language* says that it's undefined behavior. UB *may* "work" for some definition of "working", but it isn't protected by the C++ specification.

Comment: @NicolBolas:  Yes - I understand that.  But I have this thing called curiosity and it makes me suspect there might be a reason for disallowing it and thus an example that would demonstrate it.

Comment: @MarkWilkins: Just make a class where the destructor fails/crashes when one of the private member values is zero. If the class is properly contained, then that shouldn't be possible. `memset`ing such an object to zero causes something to happen that is in violation of the rules of C++ (ie: modifying private members without the proper protection); hence undefined behavior.

Comment: @NicolBolas- I was assuming that the object would be completely unused until after the bytes were copied back in.  Would this change your response?

Comment: @NicolBolas:  I just now ran that experiment.  I verified that the destructor would cause an access violation if a pointer was NULL.  I then did the memset of the class to zeros, verified the contents were indeed zero, then restored the saved data from the class, and the destructor worked fine (no crash).  I apparently did not understand the test case you defined.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general, no. There's an explicit guarantee that this works for trivially copyable types on §3.9/2, but there's no such thing for other types.

> For any object (other than a base-class subobject) of trivially
>   copyable type `T`, whether or not the object holds a valid value of type
>   `T`, the underlying bytes (1.7) making up the object can be copied into
>   an array of `char` or `unsigned char`. If the content of the array of
>   `char` or `unsigned char` is copied back into the object, the object shall
>   subsequently hold its original value. [*Example:*
>
> ```
> #define N sizeof(T)
> char buf[N];
> T obj;
> // obj initialized to its original value
> std::memcpy(buf, &obj, N);
> // between these two calls to std::memcpy,
> // obj might be modified
> std::memcpy(&obj, buf, N);
> // at this point, each subobject of obj of scalar type
> // holds its original value
> ```
>
> *—end example* ]

Comment: Awesome!  That said, do you know what specifically breaks if T is not trivially copyable?

Comment: @templatetypedef I've been trying to come up with some reason that would make it break, but, unless you access the copied bytes, I'm having trouble coming up with a compelling example (that doesn't involve a hypothetical Hell++ implementation). Don't know if that's just due to my lack of imagination.

Comment: Looks to me like nothing *specifically* breaks. It's just undefined. The quoted part here defines the behavior for "trivially copyable" types, but says nothing about other types. I suspect that the standard *could* have defined it for other types under specific circumstances, but it would have required *enumerating* all those circumstances, which isn't easy and could end up "over-specifying." However, there's also no particular reason it *couldn't* work for other types, so the standard doesn't explicitly *disallow* the action, either.

Comment: @RobKennedy: Is it undefined or unspecified? I thought undefined was explicitly called out in the standard.

Comment: @Loki: it's on §1.3.24: "Undefined behavior may be expected when this International Standard omits any explicit definition of
behavior or when a program uses an erroneous construct or erroneous data."

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: It's very easy to break this. Simply crash in the destructor if one of the private members is ever zero, and make sure that none of the members or friends ever set the variable to zero. By C++, if a member variable is private, and no members or friends set that variable to zero, that variable *cannot be zero* without doing something that provokes UB. Therefore, by the rules of C++, code that would crash the destructor if the member is zero could never be called. And yet, doing this "copy" would cause that to be called. Thus, undefined behavior must have happened.

Answer (score 1):

In general, yes. The only way things break is if you access the object after destroying the object and before the restitution of it's data:

memset(&o, 0, sizeof(o));

obj.doSomething();  <--- breaks

memcpy(&o, bytes, sizeof(o));

Comment: I was assuming that there are no intervening operations on the object while its bytes have been temporarily destroyed.  But thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Would anything prohibit a C++ implementation from maintaining a linked list of *all* non-POD objects and scanning that list every time any time anything anything in memory is modified (but regarding compiler-generated changes to the structure as atomic)?  Such a thing would be horribly slow, of course, but would anything prohibit it?